# Overwrite CSS min-width on image in Safari/Chrome

Tags: css

I am overwriting the min-width style from 100% to auto which works fine in Firefox but not in Safari and Chrome. I can't figure out why..?!

Find my samle code below or http://jsfiddle.net/zxsbodLp/:

```css
div img {
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
}

div.small img {
    min-width: auto;
    max-width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="400" height="200" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="small">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" width="400" height="200" alt="" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work.

```
min-width: initial!important;
```

Comment: Note that `min-width: initial` will be not supported in the IE10 & IE11. Either you need to apply both `auto` & `initial` css or use some logic to apply css based on browser.

Comment: @Jayesh I dont care about internet explorer anymore. It's not a current web browser.

Comment: Yes. But sometimes we have clients which are using old browsers :)

Comment: @Jayesh Microsoft stopped supporting internet explorer in January 2016, and internet explorer does not support the modern web. It would be a travesty to write web apps for internet explorer compatibility in this day and age.

Answer (score -1):

As I don't really like the usage of !important in the provided answer and I'm not familiar with value 'initial' I'll try to test out my solution to the same issue. Looking at the https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-width I wonder why would:

```
min-width: 0;
```

not be answer? Essentially that's the default value.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your recommendation does not work.

Comment: doesn't work where? I have successfully applied this on production site which supports IE9+, FF, Chrome, Safari and Opera. And clarification I'm only showing here min-width solution.